# Probability questions : roll a fair die and compose a box with x colored balls

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability

We roll a fair die and compose a box with 11 colored balls. Of these, the number of green balls is equal to the number obtained by rolling the dice. We then proceed by extracting a ball from the box. To calculate

- the probability of getting a green ball out of the box Answer
- the probability that there are 4 green balls in the box, if the ball
  we have extracted is green Answer

We now proceed by extracting 2 balls from the box with putting them inside again. To calculate

- the probability of pulling at least one green ball out of the box.
  Answer

ps. i actually don't know where to start.

Comment: What have you tried here?  This seems like a straightforward exercise in "Total Probability"...  What is the chance that you rolled a $1$?  Given that you rolled a $1$ what is the probability that you drew a green ball?  What is the chance you rolled a $2$?  Given that you rolled a $2$ what is the probability that you drew a green ball?  Continue in this fashion up to rolling a $6$...  Combine the results in the obvious way for a final answer.

Comment: What have you tried?  Note:  the wording is unclear.  When you say "the probability that there are $4$ green balls" do you mean "exactly $4$" or "at least $4$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem

Comment: @JMoravitz thanks for the input

Comment: What is "reimbussing" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, since we are rolling a fair die, we are likely to get an integer from 1 to 6 with equal probability (1/6 for each). Hence the probability of having 1 green ball in the box is 1/6, same as the probability of having 2, 3, 4 , 5 or 6 green balls in the box.

Hence,
P(Getting a green ball out of the box)
= (1/6)*(1/11) + (1/6)*(2/11) + (1/6)*(3/11) + (1/6)*(4/11) + (1/6)*(5/11) + (1/6)*(6/11)
= (1/6)*(21/11)
= 7/22

For the second part, we are conditioning P(4 green balls in the box) on P(Getting a green ball out of the box).
P(4 green balls in the box)= P(rolling a 4 on dice) = 1/6
P(P(4 green balls in the box ∩ getting a green ball out of the box) = (1/6)*(4/11) = 2/33

P(4 green balls in the box | Getting a green ball out of the box) = (2/33)/(7/22) = 4/21

For the third part,
P(Getting at least 1 green ball) = 1 - P(Getting no green balls)

P(Getting no green balls)
= (1/6)*(10/11) + (1/6)*(9/11) + (1/6)*(8/11) + (1/6)*(7/11) + (1/6)*(6/11) + (1/6)*(5/11)
= (1/6)*(45/11)
= 15/22

P(Getting at least 1 green ball) = 1 - 15/22 = 7/22.

Comment: Thanks you , with the input given me up there i was able to do 1 and 2 anyway thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm glad to help!